# How do I add an optional global request header to openapi/swagger 3 documentation in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I have a spring boot project that uses openapi/swagger 3 annotations for documentation.  Since the project is behind a Zuul gateway, there is some pre-processing of requests before they reach specific REST endpoints.  Some of that pre-processing is controlled by an optional custom header - eg, X-Custom-Header.  I want to add the ability to send that header on all requests into the system, but since it's not used in any of the actual endpoint logic, I don't want to have to add the header field to every endpoint method.  I was hoping it would be possible to modify the OpenAPI object, similarly to how we add a security scheme, but I can't find anything that creates the requisite functionality.  Am I missing anything?